# No puedo recibir el valor de una query SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito extraer un único valor de la base de datos para asignarla a una variable `int` y luego usarla, pero no puedo obtenerla.

Probe la sintaxis de la query y me retorna el valor que necesito, el problema es que no puedo asignarla, me retorna el siguiente error en la linea 5:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error de lectura porque no hay datos.'
```

```cs
con.Open();
string str = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM productosencola ORDER BY Id DESC;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int idmax = int.Parse(rdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
```

Comment: Has mirado si en la base de datos que solicitas está bien escrita y hay datos?

Comment: Si hice la prueba de esa consulta directamente en el explorador de objetos de sql y el resultado que muestra es el resultado q necesito el id al que estoy apuntando en la query es el primarykey tipo int de esa tabla y es un campo identidad(nose si eso tenga algo que ver con el problema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que necesitas leer ese datareader. Para ello deberías primero comprobar si tiene alguna fila y si tiene puedes ir recorriendolas con el método `.Read()`, después de esto ya podrás obtener el valor con `GetValue()` te dejo un ejemplo:

```
con.Open();
string str = "SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM productosencola ORDER BY Id DESC;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int idmax = -1;

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
      idmax = int.Parse(rdr.GetValue(0).ToString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar la variable de la siguiente forma:

```
select @EmpID = ID from productosencola
```

Adjunto [respuesta más completa en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973224/how-to-convert-varchar-to-int-in-sql-server-2008) para que puedas ver si esto no te funciona.

Comment: `Int int= "SELECT CAST(Id AS INT) FROM productosencola` esto en c# no se puede hacer

Comment: @miguel como no especifica que era en C# puse todo lo posible, de todas formas respuesta editada

Answer (score 0):

Yo uso esta sintaxis

int valor = rdr["Id"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : (int) rdr["Id"];

Lo que hay entre comillas dobles es el nombre de la columna o el "apodo" que le opones en el SELECT mediante la palabra reservada AS

De esta manera si es NULL el valor en la DB te devuelve 0 y si no te guarda en valor lo que haya traído el SELECT como Id.

Saludos